# Separating the Nybbles in a Byte with Bitwise Operators in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

If we have a decimal value: **123**
and its binary version: **01111011**

How can I get four leftmost and the four rightmost bits from this byte into 2 separate `int` variables?

I mean:

```
int a = 7;  // 0111 (the first four bits from the left)
int b = 11; // 1011 (the first four bits from the right)
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int x = 123;
int low = x & 0x0F;
int high = (x & 0xF0) >> 4;
```

This is called *masking* and *shifting*. By `AND`ing with `0xF` (which is binary `00001111`) we remove the higher four bits. `AND`ing with `0xF0` (which is binary `11110000`) removes the lower four bits. Then (in the latter case), we shift to the right by 4 bits, in effect, pushing away the lower 4 bits and leaving only what were the upper 4 bits.

As @owlstead says in the comments below, there's another way to get the higher bits. Instead of masking the lower bits then shifting, we can just shift.

`int high = x >> 4;`

Note that we don't need to mask the lower bits since whatever they were, they're gone (we've pushed them out). The above example is clearer since we explicitly zero them out first, but there's no need to do so for this particular example.

But to deal with numbers bigger than 16 bits (`int` is usually 32 bits), we still need to mask, because we can have the *even higher* sixteen bits getting in the way!

`int high = (x >> 4) & 0x0F;`

Comment: I always perform the `&` in the end as it is more clear and works on 16 bit numbers as well.

Comment: @owlstead six of one, half a dozen of the other :)

Comment: Doing the masking last also helps avoid problems with sign extension, if the input happens to be negative.

Comment: @owlstead Revised to include a variation on your suggestion.